# Workaround for TotalMinutes functionality in EF query?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following query.

```
var query = DbContext.Trucks
    .Where(t => t.Facility.Company.CompanyCode == companyCode)
    .Where(t => t.Departure >= startMonth && t.Departure < endMonth);

if (customerId.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(t => t.PurchaseOrder.CustomerId == customerId);

var results = await query.GroupBy(t => new { t.Departure!.Value.Year, t.Departure!.Value.Month })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Month = new DateTime(g.Key.Year, g.Key.Month, 1),
        Dwell = g.Average(t => (t.Departure!.Value - t.Arrival).TotalMinutes)
    })
    .ToDictionaryAsync(g => g.Month, g => g.Dwell);
```

Currently, the query fails.

```
The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:
KeySelector: new { 
    Year = DATEPART(year, t.Departure), 
    Month = DATEPART(month, t.Departure)
 }, 
GroupingEnumerable:ShapedQueryExpression: 
    QueryExpression: 
        Projection Mapping:
            Outer.Outer -> EntityProjectionExpression: Truck
            Outer.Inner -> EntityProjectionExpression: Facility
            Inner -> EntityProjectionExpression: Company
        SELECT 1
        FROM Trucks AS t
        INNER JOIN Facilities AS f ON t.FacilityId == f.Id
        INNER JOIN Companies AS c ON f.CompanyId == c.Id
        WHERE ((c.CompanyCode == @__companyCode_0) && ((t.Departure >= @__startMonth_1) && (t.Departure < @__endMonth_2))) && ((DATEPART(year, t.Departure) == DATEPART(year, t.Departure)) && (DATEPART(month, t.Departure) == DATEPART(month, t.Departure)))
    ShaperExpression: new TransparentIdentifier<TransparentIdentifier<Truck, Facility>, Company>(
            Outer = new TransparentIdentifier<Truck, Facility>(
                Outer = EntityShaperExpression: 
                    PegasusEntities.Models.Truck
                    ValueBufferExpression: 
                        ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Outer
                    IsNullable: False
                , 
                Inner = EntityShaperExpression: 
                    PegasusEntities.Models.Facility
                    ValueBufferExpression: 
                        ProjectionBindingExpression: Outer.Inner
                    IsNullable: False
            ), 
            Inner = EntityShaperExpression: 
                PegasusEntities.Models.Company
                ValueBufferExpression: 
                    ProjectionBindingExpression: Inner
                IsNullable: False
        )

    .AsQueryable()
    .Average(e => (e.Outer.Outer.Departure.Value - e.Outer.Outer.Arrival).TotalMinutes)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

I believe I've isolated the problem to `TimeSpan.TotalMinutes` (in the assignment to `Dwell`), which apparently cannot be translated to SQL.

Short of asking Microsoft to add support for this, has anyone figured out a workaround for it? Running this on the client side would require pulling down a load of data that I don't need.

Comment: For what it's worth, this issue was reported in GitHub and closed in October 2022: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19360

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use [EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions)

ie change

```
(t.Departure!.Value - t.Arrival).TotalMinutes
```

to something like

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffMinute(t.Arrival, t.Departure.Value)
```

Note that DATEDIFF counts boundary-crossings, while TimeSpan.TotalMinutes is like TimeSpan.TotalSeconds/60.  So automatically translating TimeSpan.TotalMinutes to DateDiffMinute would be dangerous.  If that's the required output you can use something like:

```
EF.Functions.DateDiffSecond(t.Arrival, t.Departure.Value) / 60.0
```

Other databases handle this scenario differently.  EG Oracle and I think Postgres allow datetime arithmetic in SQL and so allow you to simply subtract dates.  So the answer really provider-specific.

Comment: Typical MSFT answer. This is SqlServer specific method. How about other databases? You MSFTs seem to think the word is only MS :(

Comment: Yes, that appears to be working. Thanks!

Comment: @IvanStoev clarified that this is provider-specific.  I assumed it was SQL Server because the SQL Server provider doesn't translate that expression, although there are probably others that don't either.