# Sum hours in a select

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I want to Sum the TotalMinutes of my Activity Table grouped by all the persons.

```
var activitieIds = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

var spendHours = await _context.Activities
            .Where(x => activitieIds.Contains(x.Id))
            .GroupBy(g => g.PersonId)
            .Select(x => new StatisticsDto
            {
                 Label = x.Key.ToString(),
                 Value = (long)x.Sum(x => (x.EndDate - x.StartDate).TotalMinutes)
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

Result should look like this:
PersonenId SpendMinutes
1          260
2          300
4          120
....

My error:
.StartDate).TotalMinutes' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().

Thanks

Comment: you tested this  post https://stackoverflow.com/a/75009811/10193401